# JQuery and XHR Request asyncronious issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asynchronous

I'm trying to manage to apply an generated image of an audio graph for every div that a music url is found with a Google Chrome Extension.

However, the process of downloading the music from the url and processing the image, takes enough time that all of the images keep applying to the last div.

I'm trying to apply the images to each div as throughout the JQuery's each request. All the div's have the `/renderload.gif` gif playing, but only the last div flashes as the images finished processing one by one.

Example being that the src is being set to `/renderload.gif` for all 1,2,3,4,5

but once the sound blob was downloaded and image was generated, only 4-5 gets the images and it continues on loading the queue, repeating the issue.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to deal with.
[image]

Here's my latest attempts to add queueing to avoid lag by loading all the audios at once, but it seems the issue still persists.

```
// context.js
function Queue(){
  var queue  = [];
  var offset = 0;
  this.getLength = function(){
    return (queue.length - offset);
  }
  this.isEmpty = function(){
    return (queue.length == 0);
  }
  this.setEmpty = function(){
    queue = [];
    return true;
  }
  this.enqueue = function(item){
    queue.push(item);
  }
  this.dequeue = function(){
    if (queue.length == 0) return undefined;
    var item = queue[offset];
    if (++ offset * 2 >= queue.length){
      queue  = queue.slice(offset);
      offset = 0;
    }
    return item;
  }
  this.peek = function(){
    return (queue.length > 0 ? queue[offset] : undefined);
  }
}


var audioqueue=new Queue();
var init=0;
var current=0;
var finished=0;


function RunGraphs(x) {
    if (x==init) {
        if (audioqueue.isEmpty()==false) {
            current++;
            var das=audioqueue.dequeue();
            var divparent=das.find(".original-image");
            var songurl=das.find(".Mpcs").find('span').attr("data-url");
            console.log("is song url "+songurl);
            console.log("is data here "+divparent.attr("title"));
            divparent.css('width','110px');
            divparent.attr('src','https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a4/f2/cb/a4f2cb80ff2ae2772e80bf30e9d78d4c.gif');
            var blob = null;
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
            xhr.open("GET",songurl,true); 
            xhr.responseType = "blob";//force the HTTP response, response-type header to be blob
            xhr.onload = function() {
                blob = xhr.response;//xhr.response is now a blob object
                console.log(blob);
                SCWFRobloxAudioTool.generate(blob, {
                    canvas_width: 110,
                    canvas_height: 110,
                    bar_width: 1,
                    bar_gap : .2,
                    wave_color: "#ecb440",
                    download: false,
                    onComplete: function(png, pixels) {
                        if (init == x) {
                            divparent.attr('src',png);
                            finished++;
                        }
                    }
                }); 
            }
            xhr.send();
            OnHold(x);
        }
    }
}
function OnHold(x) {
    if (x==init) {
        if (current > finished+7) {
            setTimeout(function(){
                OnHold(x)
            },150)
        } else {
            RunGraphs(x)
        }
    }
}
if (window.location.href.includes("/lib?Ct=DevOnly")){
    functionlist=[];
    current=0;
    finished=0;
    init++;
    audioqueue.setEmpty();
    $(".CATinner").each(function(index) {
        (function(x){
            audioqueue.enqueue(x);
        }($(this)));
    });
    RunGraphs(init);
};
```

The SCWFAudioTool is from this github repository.
[Soundcloud Waveform Generator](https://github.com/Idnan/SoundCloud-Waveform-Generator)

The Queue.js from a search request, slightly modified to have setEmpty support.[Queue.js](http://code.stephenmorley.org/javascript/queues/)

Comment: You should call `RunGraph` directly with `$(this)` instead of using an imediatly invoked function, like this `RunGraph($(this))`

Comment: Doesn't resolve my main issue that I'm trying to resolve.

Comment: Add your html too.

Comment: You are redefining `divparent` at this line `var divparent=divparent;`. Try by deleting this line.

Comment: Don't believe that would have any effect to the needed output of this javascript; but otherwise, I've changed it.

Comment: Even if, iy hsa no effect, it's useless to keep it and it can confuse those who can help.

Comment: Please check the status of your XHR requests like so:
`var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
[...]
request.onload = function () {
    if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
        // OK
    } else {
        // FAIL
    }
};
request.onerror = function () {
    // FAIL
}
request.send();` and verify that there are no errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please read the edit part of the post**

I mad a usable minimal example of your code in order to check your Queue and defer method. there seems to be no error that i can find (i don't have the html file and cant check for missing files. Please do that yourself by adding the `if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400)` check to the onload callback):

```js
// context.js
function Queue(){
  var queue  = [];
  var offset = 0;
  this.getLength = function(){
    return (queue.length - offset);
  }
  this.isEmpty = function(){
    return (queue.length == 0);
  }
  this.setEmpty = function(){
    queue = [];
    return true;
  }
  this.enqueue = function(item){
    queue.push(item);
  }
  this.dequeue = function(){
    if (queue.length == 0) return undefined;
    var item = queue[offset];
    if (++ offset * 2 >= queue.length){
      queue  = queue.slice(offset);
      offset = 0;
    }
    return item;
  }
  this.peek = function(){
    return (queue.length > 0 ? queue[offset] : undefined);
  }
}


var audioqueue=new Queue();
var init=0;
var current=0;
var finished=0;


function RunGraphs(x) {
    if (x==init) {
        if (audioqueue.isEmpty()==false) {
            current++;
            var songurl = audioqueue.dequeue();
            
            console.log("is song url "+songurl);
            var blob = null;
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
            xhr.open("GET",songurl,true);
            xhr.responseType = "blob";//force the HTTP response, response-type header to be blob
            xhr.onload = function() {
                
                if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
                    blob = xhr.response;//xhr.response is now a blob object
                    console.log('OK');
                    finished++;
                } else {
                    console.log('FAIL');
                }
            }
            xhr.send();
            OnHold(x);
        }
    }
}
function OnHold(x) {
    if (x==init) {
        if (current > finished+7) {
            setTimeout(function(){
                OnHold(x)
            },150)
        } else {
            RunGraphs(x)
        }
    }
}

var demoObject = new Blob(["0".repeat(1024*1024*2)]); // 2MB Blob
var demoObjectURL = URL.createObjectURL(demoObject);
if (true){
    functionlist=[];
    current=0;
    finished=0;
    init++;
    audioqueue.setEmpty();
    for(var i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        audioqueue.enqueue(demoObjectURL);
    RunGraphs(init);
};
```

Therefore if there are no errors left concerning missing files the only errors i can think off is related to the `SCWFRobloxAudioTool.generate` method.

Please check if the callback gets triggered correctly and that no errors accrue during conversion.

If you provide additional additional info, data or code i can look into this problem.

### EDIT:

I looked into the 'SoundCloudWaveform' program and i think i see the problem:

The module is not made to handle multiple queries at once (there is only one global setting object. So every attempt to add another query to the api will override the callback of the previous one, and since the fileReader is a async call only the latest added callback will be executed.)

Please consider using an oop attempt of this api:

```js
window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;

Array.prototype.max = function() {
  return Math.max.apply(null, this);
};

function SoundCloudWaveform (){

 this.settings = {
  canvas_width: 453,
  canvas_height: 66,
  bar_width: 3,
  bar_gap : 0.2,
  wave_color: "#666",
  download: false,
  onComplete: function(png, pixels) {}
 }

 this.generate = function(file, options) {

  // preparing canvas
  this.settings.canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  this.settings.context = this.settings.canvas.getContext('2d');

  this.settings.canvas.width = (options.canvas_width !== undefined) ? parseInt(options.canvas_width) : this.settings.canvas_width;
  this.settings.canvas.height = (options.canvas_height !== undefined) ? parseInt(options.canvas_height) : this.settings.canvas_height;

  // setting fill color
  this.settings.wave_color = (options.wave_color !== undefined) ? options.wave_color : this.settings.wave_color;

  // setting bars width and gap
  this.settings.bar_width = (options.bar_width !== undefined) ? parseInt(options.bar_width) : this.settings.bar_width;
  this.settings.bar_gap = (options.bar_gap !== undefined) ? parseFloat(options.bar_gap) : this.settings.bar_gap;

  this.settings.download = (options.download !== undefined) ? options.download : this.settings.download;

  this.settings.onComplete = (options.onComplete !== undefined) ? options.onComplete : this.settings.onComplete;

  // read file buffer
  var reader = new FileReader();
        var _this = this;
        reader.onload = function(event) {
           var audioContext = new AudioContext()
            audioContext.decodeAudioData(event.target.result, function(buffer) {
                audioContext.close();
                _this.extractBuffer(buffer);
            });
        };
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
 }

 this.extractBuffer = function(buffer) {
     buffer = buffer.getChannelData(0);
     var sections = this.settings.canvas.width;
     var len = Math.floor(buffer.length / sections);
     var maxHeight = this.settings.canvas.height;
     var vals = [];
     for (var i = 0; i < sections; i += this.settings.bar_width) {
         vals.push(this.bufferMeasure(i * len, len, buffer) * 10000);
     }

     for (var j = 0; j < sections; j += this.settings.bar_width) {
         var scale = maxHeight / vals.max();
         var val = this.bufferMeasure(j * len, len, buffer) * 10000;
         val *= scale;
         val += 1;
         this.drawBar(j, val);
     }

     if (this.settings.download) {
      this.generateImage();
     }
     this.settings.onComplete(this.settings.canvas.toDataURL('image/png'), this.settings.context.getImageData(0, 0, this.settings.canvas.width, this.settings.canvas.height));
     // clear canvas for redrawing
     this.settings.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.settings.canvas.width, this.settings.canvas.height);
    },

    this.bufferMeasure = function(position, length, data) {
        var sum = 0.0;
        for (var i = position; i <= (position + length) - 1; i++) {
            sum += Math.pow(data[i], 2);
        }
        return Math.sqrt(sum / data.length);
    },

    this.drawBar = function(i, h) {

     this.settings.context.fillStyle = this.settings.wave_color;

  var w = this.settings.bar_width;
        if (this.settings.bar_gap !== 0) {
            w *= Math.abs(1 - this.settings.bar_gap);
        }
        var x = i + (w / 2),
            y = this.settings.canvas.height - h;

        this.settings.context.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
    },

    this.generateImage = function() {
     var image = this.settings.canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

     var link = document.createElement('a');
     link.href = image;
     link.setAttribute('download', '');
     link.click();
    }
}

console.log(new SoundCloudWaveform());
```

Also consider simply using an array for the queue:

```js
function Queue(){
  var queue  = [];
  var offset = 0;
  this.getLength = function(){
    return (queue.length - offset);
  }
  this.isEmpty = function(){
    return (queue.length == 0);
  }
  this.setEmpty = function(){
    queue = [];
    return true;
  }
  this.enqueue = function(item){
    queue.push(item);
  }
  this.dequeue = function(){
    if (queue.length == 0) return undefined;
    var item = queue[offset];
    if (++ offset * 2 >= queue.length){
      queue  = queue.slice(offset);
      offset = 0;
    }
    return item;
  }
  this.peek = function(){
    return (queue.length > 0 ? queue[offset] : undefined);
  }
}

var q = new Queue();
q.enqueue(1)
q.enqueue(2)
q.enqueue(3)
console.log(q.dequeue());
console.log(q.dequeue());
console.log(q.dequeue());
console.log(q.dequeue());


var q2 = [];
q2.push(1)
q2.push(2)
q2.push(3)
console.log(q2.shift());
console.log(q2.shift());
console.log(q2.shift());
console.log(q2.shift());
```

It prevents confusion ant the speedup of it is minimal in your application.

Comment: The alternative provided SoundCloud Waveform generator seems to cause issues with not closing previous AudioContext's and causes extreme CPU usage.

"Uncaught DOMException: Failed to construct 'AudioContext': The number of hardware contexts provided (6) is greater than or equal to the maximum bound (6).
    at new SoundCloudWaveform.."

Comment: Resolved this by adding "_this.audioContext.close();" at the end of the function for this.generate

Comment: Since you only need it in once you could init the audio context as a local variable. I updated the answer to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

On your open method on the xhr object, set the parameter to true, also... try using the onload() instead of onloadend(). Good Luck!

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(),
method = 'GET',
url = 'https://developer.mozilla.org/';

xmlhttp.open(method, url, true);
xmlhttp.onload = function () {
// Do something with the retrieved data
};
xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: Thought that I needed to use onloadend to ensure all the data was loaded, but seems there's no difference for that.
However, the problem still happens.

Comment: onload does ensure that all data is resolved from the Promise. From the way you had it in your code earlier, you were not running it asynchronously because the third parameter in open() was not set. Other than that, not sure if I can help anymore! Good luck,

Comment: @BenBrown [`async` defaults to true](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open), so I think it was running async OK before. It was for me while I was looking at it!